# Filter to exclude certain states PHP

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that accepts information about a customer including their address. I need to add a filter to the script that will look at the user's state and give an error if it is one of the states. The states are: AK, AZ, HI, and OR.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: What have you tried already? Maybe put in sample code, the more detail/demonstration that you've actually done something, the higher the probability someone will help.

Comment: You've shown absolutely no attempt to get this working. At least put some effort in before coming to SO

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of what you can do.

```
$customerState = "NJ";
$arrayOfStates = array("AK", "AZ", "HI", "OR"); //List of states

if(in_array($customerState,$arrayOfStates ))
{
  echo "This state is not supported";
}else
{
  exho "State supported!";
}
```

Comment: `Notice: Undefined variable: customer_state`

Comment: oops, that was my fault, I had 2 different variables. Copy the above code and try again.